# Reference request for topological properties of matrix rings

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, matrix-calculus

I am struggling with topological properties of matrix rings. Someone kindly give me a good reference that talks about these topics say the connectedness of $GL_n (\mathbb {C}) $ and similar things.

Comment: Lie groups ? ${}{}$

Comment: Yes with emphasis on the topological properties